# Email sent with Mail() class shows the HTML code and not the result of it

Tags: php, html, email, opencart

this is how i am sending an email using the [Mail()](http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Settings+%3a%3a+Mail) class from opencart:

```
$mail = new Mail();
                $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
                $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
                $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
                $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
                $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
                //$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
                //$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);

                $mail->setTo('test1@test.com');
                $mail->setFrom('test@test.com');

                $mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode('La reserva de tu alquiler ha sido correcta', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mailText = '
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="confirmacion">
                            <h1>Su reseva se ha realizado  correctamente</h1>
                            <p> El pago del alquiler se hará en su totalidad al momento de recoger la bicicleta en Euros, o tarjeta de crédito. También se deberán aportar 50€ en forma de depósito reembolsable, el cual será devuelto al verificar que la bicicleta se devuelve limpia y en las mismas condiciones en las que se ha recodigo. Cualquier daño o perdida de la bicicleta de cualquiera de sus partes durante el periodo de alquiler son responsabilidad del cliente y deberá ser pagado acordemente.</p>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>';



                $mail->setText($mailText);
                $mail->send();
```

The problem is that instead of seeing the HTML result, i see the HTML code in the email,

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setText()` is for text only content. Use `setHtml()` for HTML content:

```
$mail->setHtml($mailText);
```

You can set both, but obviously don't pass HTML to `setText()`. If you set both, the recipients email client will decide which to display, based on their preferences.

Snippet from the [Mail class](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/mail.php):

```
public function setText($text) {
    $this->text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

public function setHtml($html) {
    $this->html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! life saver!